# Importing JSON file in Node Typescript

Tags: json, node.js, typescript

I have tried every solution found online but it seems I cannot get my specifics resolved.

I am trying to import a static .json file into a node controller, all in TypeScript.

The error I'm getting is

> Cannot find module  './data.map.json'

I've checked the path 100 times it's definitely correct. I have tried every combination of require vs import, and every option I could find in tsconfig.json, which is where I believe the problem lies.

Below is a clean minimal example showing my setup. How can I import a static json file in my Typescript application?

*controller*

```
import * as data from "./data.map.json";
```

*typings.d.ts*

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "paths": {
      "*": ["typings.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/**.ts",
    "test/**/**.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this a while ago forgot to post the answer on here. Instead of trying to import a json file I just export a json object from a typescript file and it works great

Changed the import line to

```
import {default as map} from "./data.map";
```

and the file `data.map.ts` is

```
export default {
  "key": "value"
}
```

and you can access it just as you'd expect with

```
map["key"]   // gives you "value"
```

Comment: I remember doing this from a TypeScript tutorial, However looking at the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations it hints that only loaders such as SystemJS and AMD support this type of typing. From your code your using CommonJS

Comment: This isn't loading a JSON file however. It just loads a javascript object.

Answer (score 8):

The workaround may no longer be required since TS 2.9 [added support for well typed json imports](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports). Just add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

in your `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json`. With this approach, you currently must use the full path with a `.json` file extension:

```
import * as data from "./data.map.json";
```

instead of:

```
import * as data from "./data.map";
```